# How can I add elements to an array using recursion, and return a new array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have to create a method (int[]v, int a, int b) in java using recursion that takes an array of integers and returns an array in which between every two elements of the array there must be the value a or the value b, alternately.

For example, if an array v = {1,5,6,8}, when i call the method like this (v,0,1) the method should return {1,0,5,1,6,0,8}.

Any kind of pseudo code would help, I'm really struggling to implement this. Thanks!

Comment: Once created, arrays cannot be changed in size. We have to create a new array to "insert" element. --- I do not see the point in using recursion; a loop seems the more natural solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi- thanks for commenting. I know this, but in this case specifically I am supposed to use recursion, that's why I'm struggling as I'm fairly new to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it does what you need

```
yourMethod(int[] v, int a, int b){
    int[] newArray = new int[v.length*2-1];
    int counter = 0;
    boolean alter = true;

    for(int i=0; i<newArray.length; i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            newArray[i] = v[counter];
            counter++;
        }else{
            if(alter){
                newArray[i] = a;
                alter = !alter;
            }else{
                newArray[i] = b;
                alter = !alter;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for helping! I'm pretty sure that will do it, however, the reason I'm asking this is because I'm supposed to use recursion to implement this method. Do you have any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, we need a way to concatenate arrays, since they can't be resized in Java:

```
int[] concat(int[] p, int[] q) {
    int[] result = new int[p.length + q.length];
    System.arraycopy(p, 0, result, 0, p.length);
    System.arraycopy(q, 0, result, p.length, q.length);
    return result;
}
```

Then, we need a recursive definition:

- Base case: If the array is not of at least length 2, just return the array.
- Recursive Case: Return the concatenation of an array of the first element and `a` with the method applied to the tail of the array (from the second element on) with `a` and `b` swapped.

Swapping the values gives us the desired alternation between the values.

```
int[] inject(int[] v, int a, int b) {
    if (v.length < 2) return v;
    return concat(new int[] {v[0], a},
        inject(Arrays.copyOfRange(v, 1, v.length), b, a));
}
```

`Arrays.copyOfRange` gives us a convenient way to create an array which is just the "tail" of the current array. Calling this with:

```
inject(new int[] {1, 5, 6, 8}, 0, 1));
```

returns the expected:

```
{1, 0, 5, 1, 6, 0, 8}
```

You can make it cleaner and clearer with a couple of helper methods:

```
int[] tail(int[] v) {
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(v, 1, v.length);
}

int[] arrayOf(int... ints) {
    return ints;
}
```

Then the recursive method becomes:

```
int[] inject(int[] v, int a, int b) {
    if (v.length < 2) return v;
    return concat(arrayOf(v[0], a), inject(tail(v), b, a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. It utilizes a helper method that receives in addition to the original parameters, a target array for the results and the index representing what value we are currently copying from the source array:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {       
    int[] v = {1,5,6,8};
    int[] w = arrAltExpand(v, 0, 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(w));
  }
  
  public static int[] arrAltExpand(int[] arr, int a, int b) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
      return new int[] {};
    }
    int[] retArr = new int[2 * arr.length - 1];
    arrAltExpandHelper(arr, a, b, retArr, 0);
    return retArr; 
  }
  
  private static void arrAltExpandHelper(int[] arr, int a, int b, int[] retArr, int index) {
    if (index < arr.length) {
      retArr[2 * index] = arr[index];
      if (index < (arr.length - 1)) {
        retArr[2 * index + 1] = (index % 2 == 0) ? a : b;    
      }
      arrAltExpandHelper(arr, a, b, retArr, index+1);
    }
  }
  
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 0, 5, 1, 6, 0, 8]
```